# pause function until enter key is pressed javascript

Tags: javascript, function

new to javascript.  i know this might be really simple but I can't figure it out.  I want to execute a function. Pause in the middle of the function and wait for the user to hit “enter” key which will allow function to continue again (or will call another function to fire).

```
function appear()
{
document.getElementById("firstt").style.visibility="visible";
//here is where I want the pause to happen until the user presses "enter" key
//Below is what I want to happen after the "enter" key has been pressed.
document.getElementById("startrouter").style.visibility="visible";


}
```

Comment: Can't be done. Sorry.

Comment: It can be done. Just not in a single method. You will have to break this function into a couple parts and have the delayed code be executed from an event handler for the Enter key press.

Comment: @NickRoth yep. That's not "pausing a method", however ;-)

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 14):

**UPDATE 2020**

This can be easily achieved with **Promises (ES2015)** and **async/await (ES2017)**.

1. Here we use async/await to pause execution and wait for the Promise being fulfilled:

   ```
   async function test() {
     console.log('waiting keypress..')
     await waitingKeypress();
     console.log('good job!')
   }
   ```
2. In the utility function we immediately return a Promise, however the **await** from the test function waits for **resolve** being called:

   ```
   function waitingKeypress() {
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
       document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyHandler);
       function onKeyHandler(e) {
         if (e.keyCode === 13) {
           document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyHandler);
           resolve();
         }
       }
     });
   }
   ```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7znwy0bx/10/)

**BONUS ROUND**

With the pattern of awaiting a Promise we can also write a function which waits x seconds and then continues execution:

```
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

This waits for 1 second:

```
async function test() {
   await delay(1000);
   // Goes on after 1 second
}
```

[MDN await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a Promise is settled, and to resume execution of the async function after fulfilment.

[MDN Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

> A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a global variable to see if the javascript is waiting for a key press.

At the top of your script you can add

```
var waitingForEnter = false;
```

Then set it to true in your function

```
function appear()
{
     document.getElementById("firstt").style.visibility="visible";
     waitingForEnter = true;
}
```

Then...add a listener for the enter key

```
function keydownHandler(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13 && waitingForEnter) {  // 13 is the enter key
        document.getElementById("startrouter").style.visibility="visible";
        waitingForEnter = false; // reset variable
    }
}

// register your handler method for the keydown event
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler, false);
}
else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent('onkeydown', keydownHandler);
}
```

I hope this helps.  This is just what I would do, it might not be the best approach.

Comment: You don't seem to actually use `waitingForEnter`

Comment: And yes, I'd rather use jQuery for handler binding :-)

Comment: So would I, but there's no "jquery" tag.  The answer was requested in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

or we can inline the solution from Javalsu, and get rid of the global variable.

```
function appear(){
    document.getElementById("firstt").style.visibility="visible";
    //here is where I want the pause to happen until the user presses "enter" key
    function after(){
        //Below is what I want to happen after the "enter" key has been pressed.
        document.getElementById("startrouter").style.visibility="visible";
    }
    function keydownHandler(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && waitingForEnter) {  // 13 is the enter key
            after();
        }
    }
    // register your handler method for the keydown event
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler, false);
    }
    else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent('onkeydown', keydownHandler);
    }
}
```